# how can i test user entered google map url is valid

Tags: android, node.js, google-maps, backend, web-frontend

I have to write an API where the user will enter a URL of their location or property location. I will then store that URL as a string in the database. This data(the URL) will be shown to some app users where they can see the property location. Everything will work fine if the user has entered a valid google map URL. But if the user enters an invalid URL or image of some website URL the app is crashed and it closes.

Is there anyway to verify or validate the url from frontend or backend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code and error logs

Answer (score -1):

You can implement [PlacePicker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker) and get the url link of the place selected, so the user can pick places established on Google Maps.

If the Place object has null url link, make the url "NA"

Also, if they don't have their property marked on the map., you can let them drop a marker on the map, pick the co-ordinates and either show that location via the co-oedinates or do  ReverseGeocoding like -
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
as shown in Geocoding [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding)

The gist is, if you want to show show something on the map,
get this info from the map itself
(either url from PlaceId or co-ordinates)